# Why do I get an Error when creating an instanz of a class that has a metaclass

Tags: python, class, tuples, metaclass

```
class  Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, class_name, bases, attrs):

        a={}
        for name, val in attrs.items():
            if name.startswith("__"):
                a[name] = val
            else:
                a[name.upper()] = val

        return(class_name, bases, a)

class D(metaclass=Meta):
    x = 5
    y = 8

    def hello (self):
        print("hi")

c = D()
c.hello
```

Why am I getting this error:

> 'tuple' object is not callable
> line 20, in 
> c = D()

Cant finde the reason can someone help me out?

(code based on the teachings of the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAQEj-c2CI8 )

Comment: Because your "metaclass" returns a tuple, not a class. I guess you intended to call `type`.

Comment: Yes it returns a tuple but why this isnt here an issu https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAQEj-c2CI8.

Comment: I'm not sitting through a video, but it's an issue for you because [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) needs to return the object instance, which in the metaclass case is a _class_. Classes are callable, tuples aren't.

Comment: The whole code is at the end of the video there this is working. Can you show me how the code needs to be changed so it work?

Comment: I checked the end of that video. That code returns a `type` call instead of a tuple, just as @jonrsharpe suggested.

Comment: Yes you are right,, thanks you two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line inside your metaclasse `__new__`method, which reads

```
return(class_name, bases, a)
```

Returns a plain tuple - it should (and indeed, on the video you comment where you got the inspiration for your studies) call either `type` or `type.__new__`: there produce a new class that is then ready to be used:

```
return type(class_name, bases, a)
```

Although the video is a nice first introduction to playt around with metaclasses, (1) this is an advanced topic, and one actually can make a whole career in Python without ever needing to write a metaclass;

(2) on calling `type` instead of `type.__new__`, the video is not technically correct: it works, but it has a different effect in that the resulting class, although being modified upon its creation, will have the regular `type` as its metaclass - by calling `type` directly, all the references to the metaclass itself (`Meta` in your snippet) are discarded. If instead you call `super().__new__(cls, class_name, bases, a)` , the created class will be an instance of the metaclass (conveyed under the name `cls` in this call), and all subclasses of the created class (`D` in the example), will also have the same metaclass and be created through this `__new__` method.

One extra detail on your experiment: you are testing for attributes that starts with a double underscore ("`__`") - The Python compilation process automatically mangle all such names, (but names "sandwiched" between a pair of "`__`") to include the class name itself as a prefix - so if `D` would have a `__x` attribute, it would show up as `_D__x` in the `attrs` dict received in the metaclass -

I see in the linked video that is the example there; however this part of the code is never tested or verified: no `__` attributes are demonstrated to be preserved. It will preserve reserved "magic" names as `__init__`, though. As stated earlier, the video is not 100% good for teaching, as the author itself seems to be just showing some of his own experimenting.

And one last comment regarding the specifc error you are getting: whatever the metaclass `__new__` method *returns* is used by Python as the object bound to the name on the class statement (`D` in this case). So, `D` becames an "ordinary" variable containing a tuple, instead of a new class. When you execute `D()`, Python tries to call the object, and you get the error that tuples are not callable.